# How to sort and array by indices sequence of another array

Tags: python, numpy, sorting

Given I have two arrays:

```
array1 = np.array([np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,2,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,5,np.nan,np.nan,6,np.nan,10,9,np.nan])
array2 = np.array([np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,45,np.nan,33,np.nan,np.nan,32,np.nan,np.nan,44,np.nan,10,53,np.nan])
```

I want to get array2 sorted in ascending order of array1 elements with same nan sequence:
`[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,32,np.nan,10,np.nan,np.nan,33,np.nan,np.nan,44,np.nan,53,45,np.nan]`

Seems I could use
`np.argsort(array1)` = `[ 6  4  9 12 15 14  0 13 11 10  8  5  3  2  1  7 16]` if there's a command to move elements in array2 like : put an element with index "6" to the first not nan place etc

Any ideas?

UPD1:
I posted a related question [How to replace elements of a numpy array from two different arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69556915/how-to-replace-elements-of-a-numpy-array-from-two-different-arrays) for a case when we have to split the array for reordering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with numpy by overwriting the view over the second array for non nan elements.

```
idx = array1[~np.isnan(array1)].argsort()

array2[~np.isnan(array2)] = array2[~np.isnan(array2)][idx]
array2
```

```
array([nan, nan, nan, nan, 33., nan, 45., nan, nan, 32., nan, nan, 44.,
       nan, 53., 10., nan])
```

---

Another "cleaner" way to do this is to just sort the arrays as is, remove nans and then overwrite the view for array2 as in the previous approach.

```
ordered = array2[array1.argsort()]
ordered = ordered[~np.isnan(ordered)]

array2[~np.isnan(array2)] = ordered
array2
```

```
array([nan, nan, nan, nan, 33., nan, 45., nan, nan, 32., nan, nan, 44.,
       nan, 53., 10., nan])
```

Comment: I loved the cleaner way, thanks!

Comment: glad to help anytime.

Comment: For the second way, you sort first, then remove the NaNs. Wouldn't it be more efficient to remove the NaNs first, then sort?

Comment: correct, thats why its just the "cleaner" way not the more efficient one (which the first one is) :)

Comment: Euh, ```MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (5926, 6331, 6331) and data type float32``` for ordered = array2[array1.argsort()]. Isn'tappropriate for my big fields unfortunately.

Comment: Makes sense, let me suggest an alternate.. Did first approach work? that should not have the memory issue....

Comment: another quick question, `(5926, 6331, 6331)` is shape of which array? because as i understand you are using only 1D arrays

Comment: The first one works well.
I think it the issue of calculating just.
Not so simple, I am using pcraster fields converted to  numpy arrays, may be it converts them  as matrix..

Answer (score 2):

Remove NaN, sort, add NaN.

```py
from operator import itemgetter

#remove NaN
a = [x for x in array1 if not np.isnan(x)]
b = [y for y in array2 if not np.isnan(y)]
# a == [2.0, 1.0, 5.0, 6.0, 10.0, 9.0]
# b == [45.0, 33.0, 32.0, 44.0, 10.0, 53.0]


# sort
c = map(itemgetter(1), sorted(zip(a, b)))
# list(c) == [33.0, 45.0, 32.0, 44.0, 53.0, 10.0]

# add NaN
d = [(np.nan if np.isnan(x) else next(c)) for x in array1]
# d == [nan, nan, nan, nan, 33.0, nan, 45.0, nan, nan, 32.0, nan, nan, 44.0, nan, 53.0, 10.0, nan]
```

Note that the suggestion in Akshay Sehgal's answer is likely faster than mine, since it uses numpy directly rather than python lists and iterators.

Comment: interesting way of using itermgetter

Comment: @AkshaySehgal Instead I could write `c = (y for _,y in sorted(zip(a,b)))`, but I like `map` :). The important point is that `c` is an iterator, not a list.

Comment: python is as much about readability as it is about computation time, so either work :)