# How to replace elements of a numpy array from two different arrays

Tags: python, numpy

For an array

```
array2 = np.array([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 45, np.nan, 33, np.nan,
               np.nan, 32, np.nan, np.nan, 44, np.nan, 10, 53, np.nan])
```

I need to replace elements consequently by condition: if an element is less than np.mean(array2), it should be taken from `ordered_array_1 = [32, 10, 33]`, otherwise - from `ordered_array_2 = [44, 53, 45]`.

I haven't managed to use np.putmask, or numpy.where for that purpose, as for example `np.putmask(array2[~np.isnan(array2)],mask,ordered1)` doesn't replace elements at all. The array2 doesn't change.

I expect this result after replacement from both arrays:

```
array2 = np.array([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 44, np.nan, 32, np.nan,
                   np.nan, 10, np.nan, np.nan, 53, np.nan, 33, 45, np.nan])
```

Comment: What happens if there are more elements to replace that the ones on the list? If you have 4 elements to replace and only 3 in the list of replacements

Comment: Nothing happens )) And it is also strange (I mean np.putmask).

Comment: Sorry what should be the expected output the example I mentioned 4 elements to replace and only 3 replacements?

Comment: There can't be more elements, as ordered arrays are made from the array2 by exclusion and sorting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) + [`np.nanmean`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html) as follows:

```
import numpy as np

array2 = np.array([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 45, np.nan, 33, np.nan,
                   np.nan, 32, np.nan, np.nan, 44, np.nan, 10, 53, np.nan])

ordered_array_1 = [32, 10, 33]
ordered_array_2 = [44, 53, 45]

array2[np.where(array2 < np.nanmean(array2))] = ordered_array_1
array2[np.where(array2 >= np.nanmean(array2))] = ordered_array_2

print(array2)
```

**Output**

```
[nan nan nan nan 44. nan 32. nan nan 10. nan nan 53. nan 33. 45. nan]
```

Comment: Works. There's only a warning: 

```[32. 10. 33.]
[45. 44. 53.]
[False  True  True False  True False]
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:13: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
  del sys.path[0]
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:14: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater
array([nan, nan, nan, nan, 45., nan, 32., nan, nan, 10., nan, nan, 44.,
       nan, 33., 53., nan])```

Comment: @NikolayYasinskiy May I know which numpy version are you using? I don't get any warnings

Comment: I got numpy 1.17.2

Comment: I have 1.21.2 perhaps if you update the warning disappears

Comment: I would with pleasure, but when ```conda update numpy``` it says  something about channel inconsistency and offers the ver. 1.17.2 from another channel. How would you update?

Comment: Not sure, I don't use conda that much